how do i update nested fields in MongoDB using Golang
im updating fields using $set operator but only the non-nested fields get updated
update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{
    "name":                          workspace.Name,
    "identifier":                    workspace.Identifier,
    "user_id":                       workspace.UserID,
    "socials.youtube.connected":     workspace.Socials.YouTube.Connected,
    "socials.youtube.refresh_token": workspace.Socials.YouTube.RefreshToken,
    "socials.reddit.connected":      workspace.Socials.Reddit.Connected,
    "socials.reddit.refresh_token":  workspace.Socials.Reddit.RefreshToken,
    "socials.drive.connected":       workspace.Socials.Drive.Connected,
    "socials.drive.refresh_token":   workspace.Socials.Drive.RefreshToken,
    "users":                         workspace.Users,
}}

in this case im observing only a change in name and identifier, rest stay the same,
any way to update then aswell??
